# Confidence interval for difference between two variances?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $(X_i, Y_i)$ iid with variances $\sigma^2_x$ and $\sigma_y^2$, $EX_i^4 < \infty$ and similarly for $EY_i^4$. How do we construct a confidence interval for $\sigma^2_x - \sigma^2_y$?

I know how to construct a CI for the ratio of the two variances , but I am struggling to find the distribution of the statistics $\sigma^2_x - \sigma^2_y$

Comment: It depends on the distribution of the population and/or the sample size.

Comment: doesn't CI almost always depend on sample size?

Comment: Yes, and what are they? Also, you are supposed to accept answers. Have a look at your previous questions.

Comment: what are you referring to by "they?" CI?

Comment: The sample sizes.

Comment: It's not given. We're supposed to just assume it is equal to "n." It's like in general, how are we supposed to construct a CI for the difference between two variances for any data we observe.